# Remove item from my array with its ID

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a list of item outputted from a MYSQL database each with a checkbox next to them, using the code:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='delete[]' value='".$id."' ></td>";
```

It and the data are within a form, and basically when the submit button (see below) is pressed I want it to remove (unset) the items that's id are in the delete array (that have been checked). The form is also using the method POST.

Submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="Removecart" value="Removecart" />
```

How would I get it to remove the item using the id in the array?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest that you make an attempt, show us what you tried, and tell us what went wrong.

Comment: @MarcB maybe be a little less sarcastic and a little more helpful - especially for a new user man, come on. But like showdev said above, please show us any attempts you have made or code you tried so that we can help - otherwise, we would be writing your code for you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The script receiving the form would get the delete array and then issue a MySQL command

```
DELETE FROM table_x WHERE id IN ( delete[0], delete[1]....delete[n]);
```

Obviously you have to get the values from your script into the SQL statement and there is the minor matter of writing it in a style to avoid SQL Injection, but answers to those can be found by astute Googling....